# Android - Material.io - TextInputLayout doesnt work inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to Android & Material.io

I want to create a Form for the user to Creating an Entity inside my App, but I cant only see the Buttons if I don't use a layout. And if I don't use a layout and I use multiple TextInputs they just stack up on the exact same location:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".CreateTableActivity">
       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/create_table_table_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:placeholderText="@string/create_table_table_name_placeholder"
                app:startIconTintMode="src_in">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to remove the line that contains
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/accept"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:placeholderText="@string/create_table_table_name_placeholder"
            app:startIconTintMode="src_in">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="asdasasdasd" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! could you maybe tell me what you changed so that i dont make the same misstake next time?

Comment: Width as match_parent

Answer (score 1):

You have given the layout width of Text Input Layout to be 0dp. Either make it match_parent or give weights to the TextInputLayout.